# Is there any function in Pandas to find duplicates between multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data that's divided by date. I have a Dataframe like this:

```
X | 10/02/2023 | 11/02/2023 | 12/02/2023 |
0 |    4328    |    4579    |    8531    |
1 |    4578    |    4328    |    9205    |
2 |    8531    |    5698    |    7147    |
```

Notice that i have the same number 4328 on the first and the second columns. And the number 8531 is repeated in the frist and the third columns.

What I want to do is a result like this:

```
X |   Process  |
0 |    4328    | 10/02/2023 | 11/02/2023 |
1 |    8531    | 10/02/2023 | 12/02/2023 |
```

I just couldn't find any function inside pandas tha can cross those number like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
out = (df.melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='Process')
        .loc[lambda x: x.duplicated('Process', keep=False)]
        .assign(g = lambda x: x.groupby('Process').cumcount())
        .pivot(index='Process', columns='g', values='variable')
        .add_prefix('Dates')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index())
print (out)
   Process      Dates0      Dates1
0     4328  10/02/2023  11/02/2023
1     8531  10/02/2023  12/02/2023
```

**How it working**:

```
#Input data
print (df)
   10/02/2023  11/02/2023  12/02/2023
X                                    
0        4328        4579        8531
1        4578        4328        9205
2        8531        5698        7147
```

First use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot:

```
print (df.melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='Process'))
     variable  Process
X                     
0  10/02/2023     4328
1  10/02/2023     4578
2  10/02/2023     8531
0  11/02/2023     4579
1  11/02/2023     4328
2  11/02/2023     5698
0  12/02/2023     8531
1  12/02/2023     9205
2  12/02/2023     7147
```

Filter duplicates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
print (df.melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='Process')
         .loc[lambda x: x.duplicated('Process', keep=False)])
     variable  Process
X                     
0  10/02/2023     4328
2  10/02/2023     8531
1  11/02/2023     4328
0  12/02/2023     8531
```

Add counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print ((df.melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='Process')
        .loc[lambda x: x.duplicated('Process', keep=False)]
        .assign(g = lambda x: x.groupby('Process').cumcount())))
     variable  Process  g
X                        
0  10/02/2023     4328  0
2  10/02/2023     8531  0
1  11/02/2023     4328  1
0  12/02/2023     8531  1
```

... so possible pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print ((df.melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='Process')
        .loc[lambda x: x.duplicated('Process', keep=False)]
        .assign(g = lambda x: x.groupby('Process').cumcount())
        .pivot(index='Process', columns='g', values='variable')))

g                 0           1
Process                        
4328     10/02/2023  11/02/2023
8531     10/02/2023  12/02/2023
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael, it worked just fine.

I just could'nt understand each part of the proccess. If you would do that in different expressions, printing each step, maybe I could understand.. But I will look closer to the docs... Thank you so much!